Why does Paul break off his sentence when Chani teaches him to sandwalk?
Chani teaches Paul how to do the sandwalk:

Chani: You have to break up your rhythm. Like this.
Paul: Now, that's interesting because in the filmbooks I've studied,
the anthropologists say, in order to properly sandwalk, you actually
have...
Paul sees Chani's face:
Paul: Never mind. Please keep going.

Why does Paul break off his sentence when Chani teaches him to sandwalk?

Walk without rhythm/and it won't attract the worm...

@Valorum  The detail about not attracting worms is more about the practical reason behind the sandwalk itself, not why Paul stopped speaking.

He stopped because he realised he was mansplaining.

@DanielRoseman Can you convert that into answer?

Chani is insulted because Paul is suggesting that some second-hand information that he saw in some "filmbook" is more accurate than her first-hand experiences of avoiding sandworms. And indeed, we know that her description is correct, so he is probably about to repeat some patently false myth at that. She probably takes it particularly badly because he was acting like he already knew better than what she was trying to teach him, and yet he obviously needed to learn or he would not have been there.
Paul notices this halfway through his comment and thus stops talking.

Paul himself expresses doubt about the accuracy of the description in the filmbook in the earlier scene where he teaches his mother to sandwalk.

@JörgWMittag - Sure. That just reinforces my answer, though. Since we know that Chani's description is correct, the filmbook is certainly wrong insofar as it differs from hers. That Paul suspected it was incorrect strengthens this assumption slightly, but it is already pretty much a given.

Chani is a Fremen. She knows how to sandwalk. There is no reason to explain it to her.
Furthermore, earlier, Paul himself expressed doubt about the accuracy of the filmbook when showing the sandwalk to his mother. So, he is fully aware that the filmbook might not be accurate, which is even more reason not to use what he learned from the filmbook to explain sandwalking to someone who has been sandwalking her entire life.
